# Использование ранее созданной библиотеки в UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, dll

Есть библиотека на C# в виде dll, созданная  для  использования в проектах **WinForms** и **WPF**. Каким образом ее можно использовать в проектах **UWP**?

Comment: Ну, а что делает эта библиотека? От этого зависит многое. Например, если это библиотека с контролами, то использовать её не получится. А если бекэнд, то проблем быть не должно.

Comment: @VlaD, нет, конечно это библиотека не содержит контролов. Она содержит некий набор классов, описывающий модель данных. Эта модель не предназначена конкретно ни для WinForms, ни для WPF, ни для Console. Но, при попытке добавить ее в Reference проекта UWP, я просто ее не вижу в списке доступных библиотек. Но если я сделаю конкретно UWPLib - тогда эта библиотека появляется в списках доступных

Comment: Странно. А какие зависимости у этой библиотеки?

Comment: Да все, что создает студия по-умолчанию. Я там не использую чего-то дополнительно. Тут еще следует уточнить, что сама-то библиотека в списке все-таки появляется, но при попытке добавить выдает сообщение, что ее не удалось добавить.

Comment: @VladD, кажется дело в том, что почему-то студия считает, что UWP - Это .NET Core приложение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И правда, различные платформы .NET не вполне совместимы между собой, так как основные, базовые библиотеки имеют отличия.

Обыкновенная сборка-библиотека имеет конкретную целевую платформу (например, десктопный .NET), и поэтому не будет работать с UWP-приложениями. Для решения этой проблемы были придуманы [переносимые библиотеки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) (Portable class library, PCL), которые могут использоваться в нескольких типах проектов. Функциональность в них, разумеется, ограничена возможностями, доступными на целевых платформах.

Итак, добавим в наш проект переносимую библиотеку. Для этого нам нужно найти этот тип проекта:

[image: добавление проекта]

Появится диалоговое окно, в котором нужно выбрать поддерживаемые платформы:

[image: выбор платформ]

Выберем в нём то, что нам нужно: .NET 4.5.1 (и выше), и Universal 10 (и выше). У нас добавится библиотека, в которую надо поместить общие классы. Эту библиотеку можно добавлять в проекты на десктопном .NET и на UWP.

[image: solution explorer]

Всё, можно пользоваться!

Comment: @Vladimir спасибо!

Comment: @Sublihim: Пожалуйста!